# PHP SOAP: attribute already defined in WSDL-file

Tags: php, attributes, wsdl, defined

I'm using a wsdl-file that is working with SoapUI but not with PHP Soap

Code:

```
<?php
$WSDL     = new SoapClient('Foo/bar.wsdl');
?>
```

Stack Trace:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   Schema: attribute
>   'http://url.com/LGW/2009/:unitOfMeasure' already defined
>   in Foo.php:2
>   Stack trace: #0
>   Foo.php(2):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('Foo/bar.wsdl', Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   Foo.php on line
>   2

Anyone have any idea what the PHP-SOAP lib is trying to tell me. WSDL-file should be valid (at least PEAR SOAP and SoapUI both work without a problem).

WSDL contains several `<s:attribute ref="tns:unitOfMeasure"/>` -lines So I'm guessing it refers to those, but really don't understand how to fix this...

Comment: I think it is pretty clear, that attribute is already defined. And it even tells you where.

Comment: I know that, but why is this a problem? Same file validates Ok with PEAR::SOAP and SoapUI

Comment: This ones solved. WSDL wasn't valid after all. WSDL informed to generate multiple identical namespaced attributes. Some SOAP libs seem to validate that as good XML. PHP doesn't

Comment: @sarte: Please post the solution as an answer to your own question, and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 1):

WSDL-file had faulty instructions that suggested following XML

```
<ns:foo unitOfMeasure="foo" ns:unitOfMeasure="invalid">
  <ns:bar unitOfMeasure="foo" ns:unitOfMeasure="invalid"></ns:bar>
</ns:foo>
```

This gave the already defined error. ns:unitOfMeasure attribute is considered as unique because of the namespace declaration and cannot be redefined.

I removed the lines from WSDL-file and thing worked just fine after that.

Apperently Java, PEAR and possibly .NET SOAP libs will accept this kind of instructions although they are not valid in SOAP/WSDL-messages.